# asp:dropdown that is populated with jquery ajax doesnt pass selected value to server side when saving form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 asp DropDownList controls.  The first one the values are populated with code on the server side when the page loads.  When the user selects an item from this first list I have a jquery ajax method that gets and populates the values for the second dropdown.

```
function getSubtaksForDdl() {
    var $adl_type = $("#<%=hfADL_Type.ClientID%>").val();
var $tt = $("#<%=ddlTaskType.ClientID%> option:selected").val();

$.ajax({
    url: '../../Ajax/answers.asmx/getSubTasks',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{ _adl: "' + $adl_type + '", _task: "' + $tt + '"}',
    dataType: 'json',                
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d != null) {
        $("#<%=ddlSubtask.ClientID%>").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#<%=ddlSubtask.ClientID%>").empty();
        $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
            $("#<%=ddlSubtask.ClientID%>").append($("<option></option>").val
        (value.Sequence).html(value.SubTaskName));
            });
        }
    }
  });
};
```

This all works great.

The problem is when you save the page and I try to get the SelectedValue of the ddlSubtask dropdown in the codebehind, it is always empty ("").

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlSubtask.SelectedValue)) {
    carePlanADL.SubTaskType = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubtask.SelectedValue);
}
```

I have EnableEventValidation="false" for the page. If I take that out then I get the "Invalid postback or callback argument.....use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order 
to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Is that something I am missing?  What do I have to do to get the codebehind to recognize that a list item had been selected.

UPDATE:

Until I can figure out how to do it the right way or someone answers, I found that the selected value is in the ViewState and I can access it like this

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$ddlSubtask"];
```

at which point I can save it back to the database in the save method.

Another question now is this key every going to change, ie., I publish website, and deploy to production, will the ddlSubtask dropdownlist's key be different?...in which case this temporary solution is no solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the value of the second dropdown server side, 
because you are binding data to the dropdown client side and the server has no knowledge of it. The server still believes the dropdown is empty.

As per the OP the value can be retrieved by examining the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form property.

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["[unique ID of control]"];
```

A second option would be to store the selected value in a hidden field and read the value from the hidden control server side.

Comment: The value is in the Form object. see my above edit.  There must be someway to do this without a hack like getting the value from the Form?

Comment: I didnt knew value can be taken from form object...Thnx for sharing.

I dont knew other way than what I said storing in hidden field and using at server side.

And as you asked about ID getting change, It wont change, It will remain same.

Comment: Yeah, I went with getting the selected value via javascript and then storing it in hidden field like you said.